# best way to match these string or list?

Tags: python

```
main = ['123', '147', '159', '258', '369', '357', '456', '789']

match1 = 1374
match2 = 1892
```

here `match1` has 1, 4 and 7 But main has '147' so it matches.  `match2` has 1,8,9,2 so it doesn't matches to `main`. What is the optimize solution?

Comment: *What is the optimize solution?* - Optimized for what? Readability I assume (hope)?

Comment: You mean that 3 or more digits match and 2 or less don't match? Does it depend on the `len(str(match1))`?

Comment: main has a value '123' so if any string '3429523913' has all the value 1, 2 and 3. So, it matches. That is it will check all the element of list and matches the digits in the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to convert your inputs numbers to strings as you are interested in the digits they contain rather than actual values. You can use `str` to do this.

To solve your actual problem you want to check if there is **any** string in main such that **all** the characters in that string are contained **in** the string match.

```
any(all(c in match for c in x) for x in main)
```

Here's a more complete test program:

```
main = ['123', '147', '159', '258', '369', '357', '456', '789']

match1 = str(1374)
match2 = str(1892)

def has_any_match(main, match):
    return any(all(c in match for c in x) for x in main)

print has_any_match(main, match1)
print has_any_match(main, match2)
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

---

If the one-liner is too much to absorb, you might want to split it up:

```
def is_match(word, match):
    # Test if all the characters in word are also in match.
    return all(c in match for c in word)

def has_any_match(main, match):
    # Test if there is any word in main that matches.
    return any(is_match(word, match) for word in main)
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps use `sets` and check if one set is a subset of the other:

```
main = ['123', '147', '159', '258', '369', '357', '456', '789']
main = map(set,main)
match1 = set('1374')
match2 = set('1892')
print(any(elt.issubset(match1) for elt in main))
# True

print(any(elt.issubset(match2) for elt in main))
# False
```

Comment: +1 I like this too. It is quite easy to follow what is going on.

Comment: I've posted a slight variation on your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418008/best-way-to-match-these-string-or-list/4418219#4418219

Answer (score 1):

Here's variation on [@unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418008/best-way-to-match-these-string-or-list/4418088#4418088):

```
>>> main = ['123', '147', '159', '258', '369', '357', '456', '789']
>>> match1 = '1374'
>>> match2 = '1892'
>>> any(map(set(match1).issuperset, main))
True
>>> any(map(set(match2).issuperset, main))
False
```

Where `map = itertools.imap`